# Using Pig LoadMetadata interface and AS statement in scripts at the same time

Tags: apache-pig

I'm writing a user defined LoadFunction for Pig and I would like to be able to have access to what is written in the AS clause of the LOAD statement and to be able to return a Schema depending on it that will be honored regardless of it being compatible with what is written in the AS clause.
In other words i would like a way to access the string in the AS clause and to be able to disregard it later and return a Schema that I make.